# Why do the first added item always appear at the center in a graphics scene/view in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a graphics scene and view, and then I'm adding a single element. But no matter what x/y coordinate I give, it always appears at the center of the graphics view.

Why does this happen, and how can I make it appear at, say, the upper left corner?

This is my code:

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipseItem = scene->addEllipse(150, 150, 10, 10);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that by default, `QGraphicsScene` computes its [`sceneRect`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop) by adding all the item rectangles together. When you add the first item, it automatically uses it as the scene rect. And by default `QGraphicsView` scales and centers on the scene rect.

If you know the final or desired scene rect, set it before you add any item:

```
scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
scene->addEllipse(150, 150, 10, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to define a scene-rectangle that is shown by the QGraphicsView. I think the default view just shows the centered bounding rectangle of the current scene, which is just your ellipse. You can use QGraphicsView::fitInView to define the area to be shown explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but fitInView seems to also scale the scene, can I avoid the scaling?

Comment: Simple use the widget's width and height when setting the view rect. Also, there should be a protected "on-resize" method you can override in order to maintain the view even if the layout of your widgets changes.